# How do I determine the visibility of "objects" as defined in the C programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, c, object

This question was asked by my professor in an exam and I couldn’t find an answer on Google, so here I am.

I don't understand what objects are in C at all.

Comment: Technically, C doesn't have objects.  It has structs, but not objects.  Perhaps your professor is referring to *variables.*  "Visibility" is actually called "scope;" you can read about C's scope rules here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: (Your professor needs to brush up on his programming vocabulary).

Comment: C Doesnt have objects really. There are structs , and enums but no objects. I think this is a C++ Question maybe by any chance a mistake tag?

Comment: Hello. I haven't made mistake. It's C Programming. Actually I translated directly from German, but you can also translate that as elements, they use objects, I was confused with that question too. I told him for example if I define some 'objects' in one function and if I leave function, I can't use them in another one, because it's not 'visible' anymore. He told me that that is not conected with my question at all. So it's like saying local and global variables isn't answer on this question, right? @RobertHarvey

Comment: I answered on your question too @amanuel2, but didn't know I can tag only one person.

Comment: Then I guess you'd better get clarification from your instructor.

Comment: There are no objects in C , that is a definite.. Your professor may have mistook structs as an object for example `struct RGB { uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b }rgb;` , here your prof. may have said RGB is an object when in fact it isn't really IMO.

Comment: My PDF search engine tells me, there are over a 1000 mentions of the word "object" in the ISO C Spec, too many even to display them all. Here's the definition: "*object*: region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values". So, there most definitely *are* objects in C. They, of course have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the term "object" in OOP. They refer to the English dictionary definition of the word.

Answer (score 6):

C has objects, just not in the OO sense of an object.  Basically, an object in C is [something that takes up memory](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **3.15**
> 1     **object**
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
> values
> 2     NOTE When referenced, an object may be interpreted as having a particular type; see 6.3.2.1.

Visibility refers more to *identifiers* than object instances:

> **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**
> ...
> 2     For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is *visible* (i.e., can be
> used) only within a region of program text called its *scope*. Different entities designated
> by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces. There
> are four kinds of scopes: function, file, block, and function prototype. (A *function
> prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.)
> ...
> 4     Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a
> declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
> appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has *file scope*, which
> terminates at the end of the translation unit. If the declarator or type specifier that
> declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
> a function definition, the identifier has *block scope*, which terminates at the end of the
> associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function
> definition), the identifier has *function prototype scope*, which terminates at the end of the
> function declarator. If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
> space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the *inner scope*) will end
> strictly before the scope of the other entity (the *outer scope*). Within the inner scope, the
> identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
> scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

Examples:

```
int foo; // file scope; visible over entire translation unit.  By default,
         // the name will be exported (visible to) other translation units.

void bar( int bletch ) // bletch has block scope
{
  int blurga;          // as does blurga; neither are visible
  ...                  // outside of bar
  if ( condition() )
  {
    char blurga[N];    // this version of blurga also has block scope,
    ...                // and "shadows" or "hides" the instance declared
                       // outside of the scope of the if statement, and is
                       // not visible outside of the if statement
  }
}
```

The *identifiers* `foo` and `bar` are visible to other translation units; to prevent this, you would declare them with the `static` keyword.

```
static int foo;

static void bar( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

"Objects" is probably too string a term for 'C', but replace it with "Stuff" and we have something to work with.

At it's most basic (no pun intended) anything is "visible" after its been *declared*.

Within a *single* source file, that means listing your function prototypes at the top of the file.  Any code after that "knows" what that function looks like and can compile against it.

```
int doSomething( char* name, char* DoB, char* petName ); 

int rc = doSomething( myName, myDoB, "" );
```

If you omit this declaration, your compiler may "assume" a standard "shape" of function declaration, something like "int functionName();".  Your code will fail to compile because the signature you intended doesn't match the [wrongly] assumed one.

Across *multiple* source files, you move that declaration into a header file and include that into any source file that needs to use the function.

```
[file.h]
int doSomething( char* name, char* DoB, char* petName ); 

[file.c]
#include file.h; 

int rc = doSomething( myName, myDoB, "" ); 

[someOtherFile.c]
#include file.h; 

int rc = doSomething( yourName, yourDoB, yourPetName );
```